# Difference between System.Web.Cache and HTTPContext.Curent.Cache

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between System.Web.Cache and HTTPContext.Curent.Cache? In which cases both are used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> System.Web.Caching.Cache: this is the
>   implementation of .NET caching.
>
> System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache:
>   this is the instance of that
>   implementation, that lives in the
>   application domain.
>
> The Cache class is not intended for
>   use outside of ASP.NET applications.
>   It was designed and tested for use in
>   ASP.NET to provide caching for Web
>   applications. In other types of
>   applications, such as console
>   applications or Windows Forms
>   applications, ASP.NET caching might
>   not work correctly.

From [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

`System.Web.Cache` is the class of the caching, and `HttpContext.Current.Cache` is a property that returns a reference to the caching object in the application.

The `Page`, `UserControl` and `HttpResponse` objects also have a `Cache` property that you can use to get the reference. You can also get the reference from `HttpRunTime.Cache`.

Comment: Is Context the same as HttpContext.Current.Cache? The Context object holds data for a single user, for a single request, and it is only persisted for the duration of the request.

Comment: The context is local to a single request, but the Cache property returns the reference to the caching object in the application. The context doesn't have any caching object of it's own.

Comment: It's `HttpRuntime.Cache` with a lowercase `t`

Answer (score 3):

System.Web.Caching.Cache is class that handles cache and HttpContext.Cache is property, that contains an instance of System.Web.Caching.Cache for current context.

Answer (score 2):

- System.Web.Caching.Cache is the implementation of .NET caching (1).
- System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache is the instance of that implementation, that lives in the application domain (1).

(1): [Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1351519.aspx)

Comment: No, a request doesn't have it's own instance of the caching. That would be truly pointless...