# abount mvc filterContext.HttpContext cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I am using MVC `filterContext.HttpContext` to cache result data from the server.
Is `filterContext.HttpContext.Cache` server side or client side? Is it secure?
Can the cached data be hacked?

What's the difference between `System.Web.Caching.Cache` and mvc `filterContext.HttpContext.Cache`?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Cache` is stored server-side, in memory. The client cannot access it assuming you don't expose it to the client in some way. Sure, it can be "hacked" if an attacker has access to the box - ASP.NET isn't going to do anything to protect these cached values in memory. If you mean, "Does a client have direct access to these values", the answer is no - assuming you did not build anything that a client can use to get the values. However, I would absolutely not use either of these caching mechanisms for storing sensitive information.

The difference between the two has already been answered: [Difference between System.Web.Cache and HTTPContext.Curent.Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387930/difference-between-system-web-cache-and-httpcontext-curent-cache)